# Troubleshooting Routes and States with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I should start by saying that I'm a complete Ember.js noob (and MVC JavaScript Framework noob in general).

I'm trying to figure out how the Router and StateManager work together. I've cobbled together an example from various places on the interwebs, you can view it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zdfs/qsAxZ/1/

So everything on first load seems like it's working. But there are pieces of the function that don't seem to be behaving properly. I want the CSS classes that I attach via the action links to actually be a part of the application state, but I have something messed up somewhere.

You can duplicate the problem by clicking "webcam" or "screensharing". The link will highlight. When I reload the page, the state is correct, but the highlight is lost. I'm doing something incorrectly, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I try to move the actions into the StateManager, then the `router.get("applicationController")` reference is lost.

I also can't do something like `sManager.send("goHome");` - problems occur.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks after reading your code:

- Is there a reason why you did split your code between a Router & a StateManager? In the current canonical form, your states should be classes of `Ember.State`, located inside the router.
- The `connectOutlet` method should be called from the `connectOutlets` state's hook, not the `enter` one.
- The event handlers in the router get the router instance in first parameter, not a state (cf. `goHome`, `viewWebcam` & `viewScreen`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I really don't know what I'm doing yet and a lot of this was cobbled together from various examples.

Comment: Could you explain bullet #2 in more detail? Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured out bullet #2. Updated the fiddle, let me know what else you see: http://jsfiddle.net/zdfs/qsAxZ/5/

Comment: Still can't seem to get the highlighted link on load. The view isn't available, so the jQuery selector doesn't find anything. Probably doing something wrong there. Maybe each link should be a view?